# C# how can take parameters from BD before execute configureServices from Injection Dependecy

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, configure

In a .net 7.0. I need load some data before execute the configuration Services to Dependency Injection.
` private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration)
{
var services = new ServiceCollection();

```
 string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlserver");
 string keyBd = StartupConfigurer.GetKeyApplication();
 string resultDEnc = StartupConfigurer.DecryptString(connectionString, keyBd);

 // Configurar los servicios necesarios
 services.AddSingleton<IDataConnection>(new DataConnection(resultDEnc))
         .AddSingleton<IExternalServiceClient, ExternalServiceClient>()
         .AddScoped(typeof(ISqlRepository<>), typeof(SqlRepository<>))
         .AddScoped(typeof(IDatabaseService<>), typeof(DatabaseService<>))
         .AddScoped<ISharedDataService, SharedDataService>()
         .AddSingleton(serviceLayer => new SLConnection(
                       "https://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxxx/b1s/v1/",
                       "TEST",
                       "HELLO",
                       "WORLD"))
         .AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRequestsS<>), typeof(GenericRequestsS<>))
         .AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRequestsC<>), typeof(GenericRequestsC<>))
         .AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRequestsG<>), typeof(GenericRequestsG<>));

 // Aquí puedes configurar HttpClient manualmente
 services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>();

 return services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

}`
I mean, on my database I've credentials that needs SLConnection and I want get this data before charge the method.
Can I do this, or just save them in a file like the connectionString or KeyBd?

- DataConnection save connectionString and open the connection.
- SqlRepository has generic methods to execute any SQLSentences (CRUD).

Find a solution to GET Data from Database before load ConfigureService if is possible And respect Dependency Injection, or make alternatives.

Comment: Yes, use the approach you are already using for `connectionString`. For local development it's best to use app secrets ([Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows)), and for deployed application e.g. to Azure Cloud use app service configuration section. Also worth reading: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).